# CollectionView loading slowly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

My collectionView gets it's data from Firebase. Theres a firebase variable to set the number of cells and to get download links for the cell images which are downloaded using SDWebImage. The images that it downloads for each cell are around 60 kilobytes but the collectionview takes around 5 seconds to load. Also when it does load it shows all the cell images as the 1st cell image then changes to the correct image a second later.

im using swift 3

Here's my code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        //firebase 
        FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Radio").child("numCells").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapInt = snapshot.value as? Int {

                self.numCells = snapInt

                self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates(
                    {
                        self.collectionView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0) as IndexSet)
                }, completion: { (finished:Bool) -> Void in
                })


            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }





    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
            return numCells
        }




 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

                let icon = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView


        //Firebase
        FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Icons").child("img\(indexPath.row)").child("imgLink").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapString = snapshot.value as? String {

                icon.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
                icon.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
                icon.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: snapString))
            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }//firebase end



        return cell
    }
```

Comment: 5 seconds doesn't seem that long. If you're looking to increase speed, you could either reduce the image size or lazy load (only load the visible cells).

Comment: It does sometimes take longer and there's like only 5 cells at the moment. How can i do the lazy load? @milesper

Comment: Well lazy load is just loading the cells that are visible initially, which doesn't help if you only have five. The answer below might be helpful.

Comment: Were you able to further diagnose and/or solve this issue? Exactly the same thing is happening to me right now.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for heavy requests:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Icons").child("img\(indexPath.row)").child("imgLink").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak collectionView] (snapshot) in
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        /* do whatever you need with cell */
    }) { (error) in
        /* handle error */
    }
}
```

Comment: It does load a tad quicker but after the cells all load i get the error "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code==1, subcode=0x10007cbb0)" for the line `let icon = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView`

Comment: @NolanRanolin add outlet for imageview

Comment: Isn't u can't create outlets for items in a reusable cell? @VasiliiMuravev

Comment: @NolanRanolin yes, you can, by subclassing UITableViewCell

Comment: @NolanRanolin start with it: http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/ look at `custom cell` part

Comment: I created the outlet in the subclass but I can't use it in the collectionView class @VasiliiMuravev

Comment: @NolanRanolin `let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! YourCellClassName` and then `cell.yourImageAttribute.......`

Comment: Now it loads all the cell images ad image 1 then crashes with error "Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT" (for that line). The console says that it "Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x1129bd898) to 'MyProject.cellSetupFile' (0x110001df0)"